# Mule ESB, Synchronize custom java class within flow

Tags: java, multithreading, mule, esb, mule-studio

I wrote custom java class, a special http connector in the flow with request-response mule-http connector.

[image]

But if there are too many requests calls this flow, an `IllegalStateException` occured.

As far as i know the data or variables from one thread copies to another thread and I get an IllegalState...

How can I synchronize data in my connector? May I forget to implement some interfaces?

```
public class MyHTTPConnector {    
...

}
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace. Which method throws IllegalStateException?

Comment: Is your custom java class thread safe?

Comment: No, it's not thread safe. Do I need to add synchronized to all methods? Will it enough? Should I implement any other interfaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I synchronize all methods in my class and solve the problem. Thanks everyone for assistance.